# how to catch exception in batch and sqlplus

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus, goto, errorlevel

What I want to do is to duplicate a table from one database to another. Table is big, so I guess this is best solution. To use .net I have to go in a loop and so on. Anyhow, I have command:

```
sqlplus username1/password1@database1 @E:\...\someCommand.sql
if ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO failed
set datetime=%date%%time%
echo %datetime% DONE >> %paf%\synchronize.log
GOTO end
:failed
echo ERROR ON COMMAND, %ERRORLEVEL% >> %paf%\synchronize.log 
:end
```

Then I have someCommand.sql:

```
DROP TABLE table1;
COPY FROM username2/password2@database2 TO username1/username1@database1 CREATE table1 (id,date,amount) USING SELECT * FROM table2;
grant select on table1 to connect;
commit;
DISCONNECT
quit
EXIT
```

Problem is it never goes to failed. It returns error level as 0. Even when I change username or mistype table name. Ideal would be to retrieve the outcome of command, if its successful or error explanation.

Comment: Your problem is that as long as `sqlplus` runs successfully, it will return an `ERRORLEVEL` of `0`. Errors in the `someCommand.sql` script file do not mean that `sqlplus` encountered any errors. It is a subtle difference. What you will need to do is run your command inside a batch `FOR` command and process the output of the `sqlplus` command.

Comment: how do I "run your command inside a batch FOR command and process the output of the sqlplus command"? could you give me an example please

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on [How do I handle errors in a batch file that calls sqlplus, because sqlplus doesn't set ERRRORLEVEL on error or failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350640/how-do-i-handle-errors-in-a-batch-file-that-calls-sqlplus-because-sqlplus-doesn).